# Qdoublespinbox does not allow values less than 1

Tags: c++, qt, qdoublespinbox

Qdoublespinbox does not allow values less than 1, decimal values with precision grater than 1, values in positive range 0.00 - 0.99 (for example). There is no problem with setting it´s value to 1.1, 1.11, 1,04, but not 0.5 .... it is rounding up anyway to 1.

I have tried setting range to negative values with precision, setting explicitly the numbers of decimals and the minimum value of the widget, but all for nothing.

Comment: How do you set or get the values? How do you check that the spinbox rounds the value?

Comment: Do you describe your story or do you have a question?

Comment: And if you want `0.0` to `0.99`, why not use a integer spinbox in the range of `0` to `99` and then divide by `100`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I´m setting the value by simply calling the setvalue(), and similarly getting the value by calling getValue() which returns by definition double. It is rounding the values since I can set 1.1 but when setting 0.9 it will show 1.0.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] instead of describing your code. And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I have set the value of the `QDoubleSpinBox` to `0.9` and when I print the value (using `QDoubleSpinbox::value()`), I get `0.9` as expected, no rounding involved. It would make no sense if the widget were rounding its value.

Comment: Have you checked [`QDoubleSpinbox::minimum`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#minimum-prop)?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Spin Boxes Example (accessible through QtCreator/Welcome/Examples or https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-spinboxes-example.html).

You can have float or double precision rounding issues if you get your values from a calculation with not enough precision in memory.

You can also force the local to accept dot as decimal separator as you seem to mix comma and dot: add `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::C);` at the beginning of your program. You can also create a custom double validator to accept both dot and comma by inheriting QDoubleValidator.

Comment: I posted an answer because I don't have enough reputation to post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same error that I've been finding, but I hope it could help people with the difficult that I had.
I was using the QDoubleSpinBox and it was only allowing to put integer numbers, even though it was showing the comma... Only was possible to insert float numbers, when I changed the stepType (by default was "DefaultStepType"), when I put "AdaptativeDecimalStepType" I finnally was allowed to insert float numbers.